# Does input type=files appear in $_POST?

Tags: php, html

I have this within a form and I was thinking that as its an input name I should be able to detect it with $_POST[] but I cant see it.  Which would explain when I do isset on it nothing happens.  Am I not understanding it correctly?

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files"  class="hidden" multiple="" >
<label for="files">Select file</label>
```

Comment: Have you used `multipart/form-data`? like this: `<form action="location" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: you should use multipart/form-data in the form, then try print the $_FILES

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access posted file data in `$_FILES`

You can get file name, file type, tmp_name, error, size in $_FILES

Simple exmaple is:

Html:

```
<form action="upload_manager.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h2>Upload File</h2>
    <label for="fileSelect">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="fileSelect"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

In php:

```
<?php
if($_FILES["photo"]["error"] > 0){
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["photo"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else{
    echo "File Name: " . $_FILES["photo"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "File Type: " . $_FILES["photo"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "File Size: " . ($_FILES["photo"]["size"] / 1024) . " KB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"];
}
?>
```

Comment: plus 1 for actually checking the `$_FILES["photo"]["error"]` parameter. Makes you almost unique

Comment: I was actually doing a similar test thats why I was confused.  Turns out I have a variable incorrectly named which screwed the whole thing.  All good now.

Answer (score 0):

Files are stored in `$_FILES`, not `$_POST`

[$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) variable

[Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)  on PHP File Uploads.

**html form:**

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
$target_dir    = "uploads/";
$target_file   = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk      = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
      $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
      if ($check !== false)
      {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
      }
      else
      {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
      }
}
?>
```