# set user's default image for the MySQL database with php

Tags: php, html

```
<form action = "<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" class="register-form" method="post" name="form1" encype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" maxlength="15" required/>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" maxlength="30" required/>
   <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" maxlength="15" required/>
   <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="conf_password" maxlength="20" required/>
   <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*"/>
   <button href="../index.html">create</button>
</form>
```

These are my HTML tags.
I want to put a default image for this field. The name of the image is `default-avatar.jpeg` 
I have written this code:

```
if (isset($_POST["file"])){
    $file = addslashes($_POST["file"]);
    echo "Yes<br>";  
}
elseif(empty($_POST['file'])){
    $file = "default-avatar.jpeg";
    echo "No<br>";  
}
```

So I suggested when the user chooses another file, the `$file` variable gets another value, when the user doesn't choose a file, the value of `$file` stays `default-avatar.jpeg`

But the value of the file field is never empty. When I tried to `echo` it has always some value. If the user chooses another file, the value of `$file` variable is that file, but when he doesn't the value is nothing (I thought it is empty). So the `isset($_POST["file"])` is always True. How can I solve this?

Comment: [You cannot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html). Side note: whatever you want to accomplish, `addslashes()` is the wrong tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files are stored in `$_FILES`, not in `$_POST`. So the data must be sent in $_FILES. And empty() function will help in this case.

```
$temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$error = $_FILES['file']['error'];

define("UPLOAD_DIR", "../images/users/");

if (isset($_FILES['file']) && !empty($_FILES["file"])) {
    $file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

    $uploadfile = UPLOAD_DIR . $file;//implode()

    if (!$error>0) {
        move_uploaded_file($temp, $uploadfile);
        echo "<p>Success<p>";
    }
    else{
        $file = "default-avatar.jpeg";
        echo "<p>An error occurred.</p>";
        exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (isset($_POST["file"]))
{
    if($_POST["file"] == "")
    {
        $file = "default-avatar.jpeg";
        echo "No<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        $file = addslashes($_POST["file"]);
        echo "Yes<br>";  
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that this `$_POST["file"] == ""` doesn't work, because the value of the file field is never empty

Comment: @Ani, ive just seen the comment you posted on the other answer. Because you have set the input type as `file`, you may want to view this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182801/does-input-type-files-appear-in-post

Comment: Yes, because Files are stored in `$_FILES`, not `$_POST`. Thanks for this link.